# Display different images in the same table cell using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, imagemap

I have a `imageMap` (store in the first row of a `table`) and what I want to do is, depending on which `area` the user is hovering with the mouse,to display a new image right below the "original" one (i.e in the second row of the `table`).

When I manage to get the first new image(img1) to appear right below the "original", but when I hover another area then the related picture(img2) appears next to img1 whereas I want to  replace img1 with img2.

How can i make just one image is displayed?

Here is my code :

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">

function showDetails(id) {
var secondRow = document.getElementById("shopTable").rows[1];
var img = document.createElement("img");

switch(id){
case 1: 
    img.src = "pics/helmet.png";
    secondRow.appendChild(img);
break;
case 2:
    img.src = "pics/wheel.png";
    secondRow.appendChild(img);

    default: break;}
    }

</SCRIPT>
```

and the related HTML

```
<table id = "shopTable">
<tr>
   <td><map name="samplemap">
      <area href = "#" coords = "7,140,85,180" shape ="rect"  onMouseOver = "showDetails(1)"></area>
      <area href= "#" coords = "100,140,182,180" shape="rect" onMouseOver="showDetails(2)"></area>
    </map></td>
    <img name = "topHalf" usemap = "#samplemap" src="pics/top_half.png"></img>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
            </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Rather than create a new image, just change the `src` property of the existing image.

Comment: but at the beginning there is no existing image, the cell below the "original" (ie 'top_half') is empty. So don't i need to declare a variable to store the new picture?

Answer (score 3):

You are appending a new element every time. You have to remove the existing image.

You could use the property `innerHTML` for that instead.

```
secondRow.innerHTML = img;
```

Comment: thanx, i'll have a look at that.. haven't thought to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

ah sorry guys.. so stupid! I have just realized that it is because I put the `var img` inside the function so I guess every time I call the function a new `img` is created, instead if I declare the `var img` outside the `function shwDetails` everything seems to work fine...

So here is the working code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
// here is where img should be!
var img = document.createElement("img");

function showDetails(id) {
 var secondRow = document.getElementById("shopTable").rows[1];

 switch(id){
   case 1: 
     img.src = "pics/helmet.png";
     secondRow.appendChild(img);
     break;
   // and so on...
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much it.  The `secondRow.appendChild(img);` is a bit redundant once the image is in place, but leaving it there doesn't cause any real harm.  (There is a *tiny* performance issue because it will trigger a reflow, but honest -- not enough to worry about.)

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher so I should remove the `secondRow.appendChild(img);`? but if I do my code is not working anymore. However, I am happy to improve my code if it is possible.

Comment: Leave it.  What I was implying is that you could move the `appendChild` to another spot, so you only did it once.  However, without knowing how the code you posted is called, I can't give more specific advice.  So, leave it.  It works where it is.